# Why are text not responsive in bootstrap even when em/% values are used

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If em/% values are used in an non-bootstrap layout they are responsive in bootstrap no matter what text size remains the same and when `vw` are used they are responsive. What is the reason for this how to make it responsive without media queries.

Comment: `em` is font-relative and depends on the font size of parent. Are you trying to use `vw` or `%` units?

Comment: you can kinda make font responsive by giving it a class of `lead`

Comment: @ManojKumar Even with the percentages the same thing happens but in `vw` its responsive

Comment: @SuperVeetz yes its kind of responsive can you explain why is that happening only with that class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I understood in any given document when percentages are used they are only responsive for padding, margin and other things and text are always unresponsive and they must be changed according to media queries.

Ems are always unresponsive even with padding and margin.

Answer (score 1):

The `.lead` class from Bootstrap uses `Media Queries` so that depending on what the device's screen width is, the `font-size` property will be a different value

```
/*---------------------
     Media Queries
---------------------*/
/* Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {

  .lead {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }

}
/* Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 992px) {

  .lead {
    font-size: 3em;
  }

}
/* Smartphones Landscape & Portrait */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .lead {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

}
/* Smartphones Portrait */
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {

  .lead {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

}
```

Changing the size of `fonts` depending on the size of the screen, is one of the most common things that I find myself doing with Media Queries

Comment: If I am correct in any given document font-sizes are not responsive ? Even in non-bootstrap layouts.